# Mysql XAMPP DONOT insert negative values into rows

Tags: php, mysql

How to tell the database to don't accept or insert or update with negative values from a php calculation.

consider this php code:

```
<?php include('index2.php'); ?>
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php
$mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$balance = $_POST['balance'];

$balancenow = $balance - $amount; 

if ($amount > $balance) {
    $sql3 = "UPDATE users SET balance = '$balancenow'
    WHERE mobile = '$mobile'";        

    if ($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
        echo  '<a href="index2.php"></a>';
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("You don't have enough coupon balance")';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<a href="index2.php"></a>';
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Now considering in the above example:
'amount' is of 500, and balance is of 250, 
which inturns gives us with the calc as:

`$balancenow = $balance - $amount;`

```
= 250-500 = -250
```

Now in this case, how to tell the database to not accept negative values and give out else statement instead..

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: column type is `signed` or `unsigned` ?

Comment: Why you are not check it using php?

Comment: Simple use `if ($balancenow  < 0)
{ echo "negative"; }

else{echo "positive" // insert into database;}`

Comment: column is signed as signed as int.

Comment: @Saty I added `if ($amount > $balance) {` before starting an sql query .. but seem like something went wrong, the page came error..

Comment: syntax error in this line `echo 'alert("You don't have enough coupon balance")';`

Comment: no, it dont return as error .. but simple as "page is currently unable to handle the request"

Answer (score 1):

ok, In my opinion validating from DB end is right choice, It force programmer to do code in right way.

Update column schema to `UNSIGNED INT` to store only non-negative value

> Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a
>   column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column.
>   For example, if an INT column is UNSIGNED, the size of the column's
>   range is the same but its endpoints shift from -2147483648 and
>   2147483647 up to 0 and 4294967295.

You can also validate you data from PHP but its second level.